# How to convert from DD/mm/yyyy in varchar(max) to yyyymmdd format in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Dates in `DD/mm/yyyy` format stored in a `varchar(max)` column need to be converted to `yyyymmdd` format.

The below options to convert / cast are not supported.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), CONVERT(DATETIME, wfm.date, 3), 112) 

CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CAST(wfm.date AS DATETIME2), 112) 

CAST(CAST(wfm.date AS DATETIME2(15)) AS DATETIME)
```

I'm getting an error message for `CONVERT` syntax:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

For `CAST` syntax, I'm getting this error:

> Line 1:  Specified scale 15 is invalid. 'dd/mm/yyyy/ in varchar to be converted to yyyymmdd format

Comment: Regarding the scale error, the max `datetime2` scale is 7 but you have specified 15.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, don't store dates as a `varchar`, store them as a `date` and worry about the format they are **displayed** in in your presentation layer. Therefore, you should just do:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date,YourVarcharMAXDate,103);
```

If you **must** get the format ``` yyyyMM`` (i don't recommend, change your data type of your column to ```date`), then you can use a furterh`CONVERT`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(8),TRY_CONVERT(date,YourVarcharMAXDate,103),112);
```

If the data engine can't convert the date, due to it being an invalid format, `TRY_CONVERT` will return `NULL`; you'll need to fix those values (make them valid). Another good reason why not to use a `varchar` to store a date.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps

```
   DECLARE @dt DATETIME= '2019-12-31 14:43:35.863';
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @dt, 11) s1, 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @dt, 111) s2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always just use `substring` for this. Example is shown below.

```
DECLARE  @samples TABLE
(
    Dates NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @samples VALUES 
('10/11/2018'),
('12/11/2018'),
('15/11/2018'),
('17/11/2018'),
('19/11/2018'),
('20/11/2018')

SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(Dates, 7,4) + 
        SUBSTRING(Dates, 4,2) + 
        SUBSTRING(Dates, 1,2) as [NewDate]

FROM @samples
```

Output will be a list of strings with your required format. This won't validate for you, but you can always try convert these to a date using `CAST` and it should correctly cast the `yyyyMMdd` to a date if the date is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server **2016** or newer, you can use `PARSE` and `FORMAT` to do this quite easily:

```
SELECT
    FORMAT(PARSE(wfm.Date AS DATE USING 'de-DE'), 'yyyyMMdd')
FROM
    dbo.WhateverYourTableNameIS
```

The `dd/mm/yyyy` format is the format used e.g. in Germany, that's why I'm using the `de-DE` culture to convert that string to a `DATE`. Then you can format it using the usual formatting strings as used in C#/.NET.

Answer (score 0):

```
select convert(varchar, convert(datetime, wfm.date, 103), 112)
```